# Nested VOLLEY GET Request Method not giving correct results

Tags: android, android-volley, android-json, get-request

I have two nested `VOLLEY` `GET` request. The first API request gives me id field which I am using to called another Web Service. The problem is the way I am getting the sequence of id from first request its not calling the same sequence for  second request which uses id field return by first request.
This is my nested `VOLLEY` `GET` request.

```
private void getData() {
            final JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, ApiUrls.RESERVATION, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                              final Entry entry = newEntry();
                            String Id = object.getString("id");
                            entry.setId(Id);
                           ID_url = ApiUrls.DETAILS + Id + "/";
                            JsonObjectRequest foodieInfo = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, ID_url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                  try {
                                                                              String firstName = response.getString("firstname");
                                        entry.setName(firstName);
                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                }
                            }) {
                                @Override
                                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                                    String auth = "JWT " + myToken;
                                    headers.put("Authorization", auth);
                                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                                    return headers;
                                }
                            };
                            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(foodieInfo);

                            current.add(entry);
                            adapter = new ReservationAdapter(current, getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                    String auth = "JWT " + myToken;
                    headers.put("Authorization", auth);
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    return headers;
                }

                @Override
                protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                    int status=response.statusCode;
                    if(status==200){
                    }
                    return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
                }
            };
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
        }
```

The id which I get in first request same it should be only used in the Nested JSON GET request. But it take different id returned by first request and called the another request from using that sequence. How to resolve this ?